# How to hide one item in boostrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap code.

```html
<label>Select Leave Type</label>
<div class="dropdown">
    <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-inverse"></i>
    <button class="btn btn4 btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu0" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select--
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-inverse0" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu0" id="drp0">
        <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="casual" class="list0" href="#" >Casual Leave</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="annual" class="list0" href="#" >Annual Leave</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="medical" class="list0" href="#" >Medical Leave</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code I usually use to hide whole dropdown.

```
$('.btn4').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

But at the moment I want to hide one item. Can't figure-out that. Please help me. Thank you.

**EDIT 1**
When I use

```
       <script>
        $('document').ready(function () {
           $('#drp0 li').eq(1).css('visibility', 'hidden');

        });</script>
```

This happens. 
[image]

As you can understand this is not what I need.Please give me more suggestion

Comment: Doesn't the usual way work (`remove` or `detach`)? Also, it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: @blgt how to do that? like "$('.btn4').css('visibility', 'remove');" like this?

Comment: @blgt, `remove()` is not always good if you need to show this item after. It means that you will have to recreate it again.

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake, take a look into my answer with `hide` class. It doesn't leave any blank lines.

Comment: Hey can you explain to me why you put downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use absolutely Bootstrap solution you can add `hide` class to the element you want to hide.
For example:

```
<li role="presentation"><a data-myAttribute0="annual" class="list0 hide" href="#" >Annual Leave</a></li>
```

Here's example on BootPly: http://www.bootply.com/q7gTTiFzOT

If you want this to be done dynamically using jQuery you can try this:

```
$('ul > li:eq(1)').addClass('hide');
```

Comment: I just want to hide this when if condition is true. So I feel hide is something permanent value. Is that right?

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake, I've updated response with dynamic addition of `hide` class. You can use: `addClass()`, `removeClass()` or `toggleClass()` to work with it dynamically.

Comment: Hi I can't find any of this in your template.

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake, take a look into BootPly URL I've specified in the answer. I've updated it with the button that allows you to toggle visibility.

Comment: Hey if your demo it is working perfectly. But I couldn't find how it to match my dropdown. Because I have several bostrap dropdowns So everything will call when 'ul > li:eq(1)' calls. I want this to happen in document load. Can you please be more specific please.

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake, You can add `id` to your `ul` if you want. I've updated bootply. Take a look. In my example I've added `id="leave-type"`

Comment: YES IT IS WORKING PERFECTLY FINE... Thank you so much. Please help me to find how to show this hidden one?

Comment: show is working.. No need. Thank you for your kindly effort. :)

Comment: @pippilongstocking, I'm happy that I could help you. Good luck!)

Answer (score 0):

Select the `li` elements inside `drp0` (which is the id of your dropdown menu) then choose which element to hide from the list that is returned (starting at zero for the first item) like this:

```
// hide first item
$('#drp0 li').eq(0).css('visibility', 'hidden');

// hide second item
$('#drp0 li').eq(1).css('visibility', 'hidden');

// hide third item
$('#drp0 li').eq(2).css('visibility', 'hidden');

// etc
```

From the jQuery docs:

> **.eq( index )**
>
> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

You might want to use `display:none;` to collapse the element:

```
// hide second item
$('#drp0 li').eq(1).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: What is eq(0) and is drp(0) mean dropdown div's id?

Comment: Please change your answer too  Then some one can gain help another time.

Comment: I keep updating to reflect the situation.

Comment: Presumably, someone didn't like your question.

Answer (score 0):

1

```
 $("li:eq(1)").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

2 or you can give every "li" a id,and then

```
$("#id").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

// hide first item

```
$(".btn4").click(function(){
      $('.dropdown-menu li').eq(0).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```